# Notify the user that firewall is blocking the iOS app

Tags: ios

How can i notify the user that a firewall is blocking the app's internet access. Is there a class in iOS which does this. If so please help.

Comment: Are you asking how to notify the user, or how to know that a firewall is blocking the app?

Comment: If it is the former, there are a number of notification libraries out there in the wild.  Natively, you could use `UIAlertView`.  If the latter, there is no way to gather this information.  Firewalls do not bother to inform you that they have blocked you, you just get no response (the same as the server is not responding).

Comment: i need to knw act the latter part.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know for sure that a firewall is blocking network access. Instead, just check to see if a particular resource is reachable. If not, inform the user that the resource is not reachable and suggest that this could be caused by a firewall.

Comment: Right now i m sending requests which gets timed out or something and thats how i come to knw abt it